# How to properly render and animate svg icons?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to use `svg files` and display them as icons. However I'm having some problems

1. I was unable to load the `icon.svg` file inside an `svg` tag. I ended up using an `object` tag instead.
2. I would like to add animations to my `svg`. I ended up doing it inside the `icon.svg` file as such `<animate dur="5s" values=...; ></animate>` which throws this error on the browser `SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.`
3. What is the best way to do all this in jade/html? This is what I have now..

   ```
    # footer.tpl.jade

    footer.footer
      +nav
      .logo.logo--footer
       h3.logo__title.logo__title--footer
         a.logo__link(href='/') Frit
         br/
         a.logo__link(href='/') Mark
         p.footer__content All rights reserved or whatever. Please refer to the about section &amp; terms-of-service for the appropriate info. All rights reserved.
           object.icon--heart(type='image/svg+xml', data='icons/heart-icon.svg')
           | Copyright &copy; 2016 Belgium.





    #_icons.scss

    .icon {

      &--heart {
        width: 25px;
        height: 20px;

        // Will like to add all the animation here

      }
    }
   ```

heart-icon.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 37 36" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;"><path class="heart--pulse" id="Heart-Icon" d="M18,11.316c3.368,-5.316 10.105,-5.316 13.474,-2.658c3.368,2.658 3.368,7.974 0,13.29c-2.358,3.986 -8.421,7.973 -13.474,10.631c-5.053,-2.658 -11.116,-6.645 -13.474,-10.631c-3.368,-5.316 -3.368,-10.632 0,-13.29c3.369,-2.658 10.106,-2.658 13.474,2.658Z" style="fill:hsla(60, 100%, 75.1%, 1);">
    <animate dur="5s" values="hsla(0, 100%, 75.1%, 1); hsla(60, 100%, 75.1%, 1); hsla(0, 100%, 75.1%, 1)" attributeName="fill" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
</path><g id="Remove-Icon"><clipPath id="_clip1"><polygon points="140.007,3.906 172.007,3.92 171.993,34.007 139.993,33.993 140.007,3.906 "/></clipPath><g clip-path="url(#_clip1)"></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: Ignore 2. It will go away in future releases of Chrome as SMIL deprecation has been cancelled.

Comment: @Robert Longson thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to display icons. Below is my working code. I used this as a reference: [SVG sprites](https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/) & this [SVG sprites css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/)

**svg-defs.svg**

```
<svg style='display:none;' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <symbol id='heart-icon' viewBox='0 0 32 32'>
            <title>Heart Icon</title>
            <desc>heart-icon-svg</desc>
            <path class="heart--pulse" id="Heart-Icon" d="M18,11.316c3.368,-5.316 10.105,-5.316 13.474,-2.658c3.368,2.658 3.368,7.974 0,13.29c-2.358,3.986 -8.421,7.973 -13.474,10.631c-5.053,-2.658 -11.116,-6.645 -13.474,-10.631c-3.368,-5.316 -3.368,-10.632 0,-13.29c3.369,-2.658 10.106,-2.658 13.474,2.658Z" style="fill:hsla(60, 100%, 75.1%, 1);">
            </path>
        </symbol> <!-- End of heart-icon -->

        <symbol id="signup" viewBox= '0 0 32 32'>
            <title>Sign up Icon</title>
            <desc>signup-icon-svg</desc>
        </symbol><!-- End of signup-icon -->

        <symbol id="user-icon" viewBox= '0 0 64 64'>
            <title>User Icon</title>
            <desc>user-icon-svg</desc>
            <g id="Remove-Icon">
                <clipPath id="_clip1">
                    <polygon points="416.013,24 448.013,24.014 448,54.101 416,54.087 416.013,24 "/>
                </clipPath>
                <g clip-path="url(#_clip1)"></g>
            </g>
            <g id="SignIn-Icon">
                <path d="M45.693,58.232c0.518,1.296 0.36,2.764 -0.423,3.92c-0.782,1.156 -2.087,1.848 -3.483,1.848c-5.633,0 -13.894,0 -19.539,0c-1.404,0 -2.716,-0.696 -3.504,-1.859c-0.787,-1.162 -0.947,-2.64 -0.426,-3.943c1.491,-3.731 3.36,-8.41 4.525,-11.325c0.668,-1.672 2.282,-2.773 4.082,-2.785c2.64,-0.018 6.507,-0.044 9.351,-0.063c2.246,-0.015 4.273,1.347 5.107,3.432c1.185,2.962 2.915,7.289 4.31,10.775Z" style="fill:hsla(0, 0%, 98.8%, 1);"/>
                <ellipse cx="32" cy="32" rx="10.581" ry="13.266" style="fill:hsla(0, 0%, 98.8%, 1);"/>
            </g>
        </symbol><!-- End of signup-icon -->

  .... omitted code
   </defs>
</svg>
```

**footer.tpl.jade** (templates)

```
        svg.icon--heart.heart--pulse
            use(xlink:href='/icons/svg-defs.svg#heart-icon')
```